# Install IBM Cloud private successfully but unexpectedly auto-logout cluster management console

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

I tried to install IBM Cloud private (1.2 ee) on a single Ubuntu (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS) VM, and saw "UI URL is https://master_ip:8443 , default username/password is admin/admin" sentence during installation process;

However, I got unexpected auto-logout from the cluster management console (back to login page) when trying to access https://master_ip:8443 w/ the default username/password. Before the 'auto-logout' I could see the dashboard page just for a while (1s). I have no idea how to resolve it, any clue or comments where to check / how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having login problems, it seems it hit the issue of expired certificates in ICp.

Can you please follow the instructions on

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/fe25b4ef-ea6a-4d86-a629-6f87ccf4649e/entry/Certificate_update?lang=en

to see if it fixes the issue?